# How to access to the active notification list

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone know how to check the list of unread notifications in the iPhone IOS? I think that there must exist a list with them.  What is the library or framework that allow us to check the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talking about **push notifications**, you can't access them.

But you can access **local notifications** with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo, I'll try this way.